# How to remove my ubuntu without installing any operating system?

Tags: 14.04, windows-8

i m having UBUNTU 14.04 in my pc. now i want to remove ubuntu and install windows8.1. I have Booted Windows in my Pendrive.. While installing It is not able to use my Hard drive space which i m using in UBUNTU says that Its is formatted in unknown format. That should be NTFS .. Now What i should do to remove UBUNTU and INStall WINDOWS? 
plzz answer me. its urgent

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to solve your problem:

1. Boot `Ubuntu` from a Live DVD
2. Launch `Gparted`
3. Select your device in the top-right combobox
4. Click on `Device` > `Create partition table...`
5. Create a new `msdos` partition table (all data on the drive will be lost!)
6. Shut down and install `Windows`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the partition table to perform this install of windows8. As mentioned earlier you should back up all your data first to an external disk and then unplug it. Use a copy of the Linux-Partition manager found on your USB-linux boot disk.

I recommend you get a copy of LMHD-Besty-KDE and flash that to disk with the  USB-image writer. See the Ubuntu / Debina help manual if your unsure how to do it?

If you can get a backup disk the same size of your current disk it will be easier to manage partitions. I use a smaller disk for booting so it is faster to backup/wipe.

The ubuntu install disk removes the partition manager. You will need the partition manager to reset the /boot flag on the windows partition & to clear any sticky-bits such as DeFrag or drive-inuse. If you choose "Make New Partition Table" These problems will be eliminated but so will your data.

You can use ubuntu-DISK tool to copy data or check the size of the data but you won't beable to make any partition table changes. Most of the Admin tools are removed when Ubuntu is installed so if you need them you will have to add them back in. I wouldn't try it unless you've done it before. You can really hose things up.

If your unsure about how to arrange the partition table get a technician to help you. Otherwise you canust use the windows partion-table manager to overwrite the whole disk. The install windows should take care of that for you but it might leave some left over linux partitions hanging about if you didn't wipe the disk.

You will need your drivers disk for the model of the PC you have to finish the install because downloading win8 drivers takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the PC, and put in the Windows installation USB key.

Boot the PC to the USB key.

From inside Windows Setup, press `Shift+F10` to open a command prompt window.

Open the diskpart tool:

```
diskpart
```

Identify the drive to reformat:

```
list disk
```

Select the drive, and reformat it:

```
select disk <disk number>
clean
convert gpt
exit
```

Close the command prompt window.

Continue the Windows Setup installation.

When choosing an installation type, select Custom. The drive will appear as a single area of unallocated space.

Select the unallocated space and click `Next`.

Windows begins the installation.